# Is $M=\{\frac{1}{k}|k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $M=\{\frac{1}{k}|k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ closed?

I think it is closed, but I'm not sure whether my argumentation is correct.

Since $(\frac{1}{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent $\Rightarrow$ from Cauchy $ \exists k_0 \in \mathbb{N}: \forall k \geq k_0:|\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}|< \epsilon ,\forall \epsilon \gt 0$

Let $O_k = (\frac{1}{k+1},\frac{1}{k}), \forall k \lt k_0$

and let $O=(-\infty,0) \cup \bigcup_{k=1}^{k_0-1}O_k \cup (1, \infty)$

$\Rightarrow M=\mathbb{R}-O$

Since O is open, M is closed. Is that argumentation correct?

Comment: You have the criterion for a Cauchy series wrong. It starts with $\forall\epsilon$. Also $M=\mathbb{R}-O$ can't be correct since $0\notin O$ and $0\notin M$.

Comment: Another possible issue is that, if you allow 0 to be a natural number, then your set contains an undefined value, $1/0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that $M=\mathbb{R}-O$; the set $\mathbb{R}-O$ still contains all the intervals $(\frac{1}{k+1},\frac{1}{k})$ for $k\geq k_0$, and these intervals are not contained in $M$.

It's possible some of your confusion is coming from the order of the quantifiers in the definition of Cauchy - you have to fix $\varepsilon$ first, and this determines $k_0$. Whatever $\varepsilon$ you choose, your $\mathbb{R}-O$ still differs from $M$ by infinitely many intervals. It doesn't even help that the length of these intervals is bounded by $\varepsilon$ - even if you make sense of taking $\varepsilon$ to $0$, so that "$\mathbb{R}-O$ converges to $M$", this convergence won't preserve the openness of $O$.

As the other answers point out, $M$ has a limit point (i.e. $0$) that it doesn't contain, so it isn't closed.

Answer (score 6):

$M$ is not closed. $0$ is a limit point of $M$, and $0\notin M$.

Answer (score 3):

Not it is not closed, $0 \notin M$ but $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{k} = 0$ which shows that $0 \in \partial M \subset \overline{M}$ where $\overline{M}= M \cup \partial M$. Thus $\partial M$ (the border of $M$) is not contained in $M$ and $M$ can't be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not correct, since the point zero neither belongs to $O$ or to $M$. In fact, the subspace $M$ is not closed, since it contains a sequence converging to a point that is not contained in $M$ itself, namely zero (Where I assumed we consider $M$ as a subspace of the real line with the usual Euclidean topology).